# Simple jQuery draggable image slider

Tags: jquery, image, slider, draggable

I have been searching for some time now with no success for a simple jQuery draggable image slider. I am new to jQuery.

This needs to display images of the same height, around 600px, across and off the sides of the page. It needs to be click and draggable, clickable for further info and also to scroll by itself when not being dragged. Please see the image below.

http://chrisfraser.co.za/Image%20Slider.png

Thanks in advance

Comment: @diEcho Thanks:) I am new here and was not allowed to attach the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at jQuery UI's draggable methods. They can easily do what you are looking for.

http://www.jqueryui.com

Comment: Thanks. jQuery UI has some amazing features. I eventually won using the .draggeble functions with a modified version of simplyScroll (http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/).